# Why Counterclockwise starts from East?

Tags: soft-question, vectors, conventions

In vector lessons, we have counterclockwise angle of rotation of the vector starts from East.

"The direction of a vector is often expressed as a counterclockwise angle of rotation of the vector about its "tail" from due East"

http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/u3l1a.cfm

Why doesn't start from north or south or any other direction? Or is it just one of common rule between physicist.

Comment: Why are maps usually oriented with N upwards? Why do clocks have 12 at the top? These are all arbitrary decisions. It doesn't matter so long as there is a well-known convention that facilitates understanding and sharing. The actual reasons for the specific choice are often uninteresting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that it can start from anywhere. It's however terribly convenient if everyone just agrees on *some* direction and sticks with it.

Why East? Because here in the West, we read from left to right, which is why [Descartes said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#History) that the direction of the $x$-axis in a conventional Cartesian $xy$-axis coordinate system should run from left (the origin) to right (increasing $x$ values) -- "due East" when put on a map that has North to the top.

When vectors came around, their direction was simply defined w.r.t. this $x$ axis -- convention upon convention.

Similar questions you should explore one day:

- Why is every world map drawn with North to the top?
- Why do clocks rotate "clockwise" and not the other way around?
- Why do most people in the world drive on the right side of the road? And why do the others drive left?
- Why are there 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute? Why not 100 seconds/minute, 100 minutes/hour and 10 hours/day?
- Why are there 360 degrees in a circle, and not 100?
- Why is the international standard kilogram a block of metal somewhere in Paris? Whoever determined that *this* is the kilogram?
- Why are there 12 months in a year, and 28/29/30 or 31 days per Month? And why do we need leap years and leap seconds?
- Why do we use the QWERTY keyboard layout? Are there others?
- ...I could go on for days!

Comment: +1, but the leap year/second stuff is actually based on physics (not the actual units we chose to jump, but the need for jumping and the average amount to jump over time).

Comment: @OlinLathrop: True, to some extent. I still think it belongs in this list. Because in fact, the year is not a nice 365.248...days. Each year, the length of the year is different, and not by a small amount too. The time systems we have designed around those facts, is in essence, arbitrary and in need of constant adjustment.

Comment: I meant that the need for leap jumps is because there is not a integer number of days in a year.  Counting time by days is not arbitrary since it's based on a real physical phenomenon.  A day is no less arbitrary than a year.  Both are based on the movement of the earth and sun.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: True. But for example, why measure it from 00:00 to 23:59:59.999..? The epoch 00:00 is rather difficult to measure, "noon" is much easier. The jumps are not "needed", they are needed to keep *our calendar* in sync with the stars. We could just as easily have thought of a different calendar system that uses 4 years as a unit. Don't forget: 4 seasons is really something for the higher latitudes; a 4-year calendar makes a lot of sense in some countries closer to the equator.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: It just so happens that Pope Gregor XIII lived in Italy, and the spread of his calendar was partially through the system of Christian churches, which just so happened to be the major religion in Europe at the time.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Anyway, before I *rally* get carried away: the *point* was that there is arbitrariness all around us :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Just to add: _Convention_ is rigorously and extensively studied by (a.o.) philosophers and game-theorists: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/convention/. (In my opinion, usually or always, the notion of convention is circularly defined, which is probably why it attracts philosophers.)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Are you sure of _Euclid_ saying what you say he said? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#History

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis if you can go further asking many questions, it means that you find the half of answer. Everything has a meaning, some we already have known and some others we have not yet known ..

Comment: @YOUSEFY: "meaning" is something humans attribute to things. IMHO, the statement "Everything has a meaning" is a nice world view, but you'd have to recognize that it anthropomorphizes the entire universe and/or implies the existence of a "higher power" -- it's at the very least not at home on a physics site.

Comment: @aufkag: No, Descartes of course, you are right. I'll edit it into my question.

Comment: @aufkag: "convention" is the act of preventing [things like this](http://xkcd.com/927/) from happening :)

Comment: I'm amazed as to how many factoids you must've memorized about all these things.

Comment: @mike4ty4: I guest that's just what happens when you get older... :)